# How to apply this title format on unnumbered chapters, table of contents, list of figures , abstract, etc

Tags: formatting

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.5in,%
            left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,%
            footskip=.50in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% fancy heading  \section %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{textpos}

\DeclareFixedFont{\chapternumberfont}{T1}{ppl}{}{}{1in}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\Huge\bfseries\rmfamily\color{white}}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \path let \p1 = (current page.west), \p2 = (current page.east) in
              node[minimum width=\x2-\x1, minimum height=4cm, rectangle, fill=cyan, anchor=north west, align=left, text width=\x2-\x1] at ($(current page.north west)$) {
                \begin{textblock*}{5in}(\dimexpr\x2-4.5in,\dimexpr0.25\headheight-1in)
                    \tikz \node [white,text width=2in, align=right, font=\rmfamily] {{\includegraphics[scale=.27]{a}}\\[5pt] \raisebox{40pt}{{\large \chaptertitlename}} \raisebox{-10pt}{\chapternumberfont \thechapter}};
                \end{textblock*}
              };
        \path let \p1 = (current page.west), \p2 = (current page.east) in
              node[minimum width=\x2-\x1, minimum height=0.8in, rectangle, fill=cyan, anchor=south west, align=left, text width=\x2-\x1] at ($(current page.south west)$) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
} {-1.75in}{}[\vspace*{.1in}]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Hockey}
\lipsum[1]

\section{football}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter*{Research Statement}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you want the small image at top right of the heading?

Comment: @ Bernard Yes Sir i want the small image at the top of heading

Comment: @ My real issues is that this format does not apply on unnumbered chapters in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use again `\titleformat`, with the `numberless` key. Here is what you  obtain (I had to use an image of mine…) and removing any code for \chaptername and chapter number. Note that it's simpler to load `xtable` with the `table` option: it will load `colortbl` automatically, and if all margins are equal, just specify `margin= …`

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.5in,%
            margin=1in, 
            footskip=.50in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% fancy heading \section %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{textpos}

\DeclareFixedFont{\chapternumberfont}{T1}{ppl}{}{}{1in}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\Huge\bfseries\rmfamily\color{white}}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \path let \p1 = (current page.west), \p2 = (current page.east) in
              node[minimum width=\x2-\x1, minimum height=4cm, rectangle, fill=cyan, anchor=north west, align=left, text width=\x2-\x1] at ($(current page.north west)$) {
                \begin{textblock*}{5in}(\dimexpr\x2-4.5in,\dimexpr0.25\headheight-1in)
                    \tikz \node [white,text width=2in, align=right, font=\rmfamily] {{\includegraphics[scale=.27]{pepe-le-pew1}}\\[5pt] \raisebox{40pt}{{\large \chaptertitlename}} \raisebox{-10pt}{\chapternumberfont \thechapter}};
                \end{textblock*}
              };
        \path let \p1 = (current page.west), \p2 = (current page.east) in
              node[minimum width=\x2-\x1, minimum height=0.8in, rectangle, fill=cyan, anchor=south west, align=left, text width=\x2-\x1] at ($(current page.south west)$) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
} {-1.75in}{}[\vspace*{.1in}]
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[display]{\Huge\bfseries\rmfamily\color{white}}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \path let \p1 = (current page.west), \p2 = (current page.east) in
              node[minimum width=\x2-\x1, minimum height=4cm, rectangle, fill=cyan, anchor=north west, align=left, text width=\x2-\x1] at ($(current page.north west)$) {
                \begin{textblock*}{5in}(\dimexpr\x2-4.5in,\dimexpr0.25\headheight-1in)
                    \tikz \node [white,text width=2in, align=right, font=\rmfamily] {{\includegraphics[scale=.27]{pepe-le-pew1}}
                    };
                \end{textblock*}
              };
        \path let \p1 = (current page.west), \p2 = (current page.east) in
              node[minimum width=\x2-\x1, minimum height=0.8in, rectangle, fill=cyan, anchor=south west, align=left, text width=\x2-\x1] at ($(current page.south west)$) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
} {-1.75in}{}[\vspace*{.1in}]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduction}

\section{Hockey}
\lipsum[1]

\section{football}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter*{Research Statement}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have nailed it in the simplest possible way . Its wonderful and awesome. Thank you for your awesome cooperation

Comment: Thank you for your kind appreciation! Note I'm not convinced that TikZ is the simplest way to obtain this result (both for numbered and unnumbered chapters).